# Can't start WinForms project because Form is a type

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a very small VS2008 Winforms project that will not start.

When I attempt to start debugging the project, I get the message:

```
'<form>' is a type in '<project>' and cannot be used in an expression.
```

From the file .Designer.vb.

The problem is that  is indeed a form.  If I create a new WinForm and set the startup object to the new form, I get the same message.

When I attempt to check the "Enable application framework" checkbox in the Project properties, I get the message "Startup object must be a form when 'Enable application framework' is checked.

I've tried creating a new project and moving all the code and designer objects to a new form file in the new project, and same result.

Other projects on the same computer run fine.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Do not edit the designer.vb file.  Restore your project from source control.

Comment: I didn't actually edit the designer file is the weird part, like I said, if I create a brand new project and move all the form controls and code to a new file, I get the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was that I didn't have a **New() function with no parameters**.  This is required for VS to see the class as a form.

Comment: Note that the **New() function** should also be **Public** (that just bit me in the ass)